# Cómo comparar los elementos de un primer arreglo, con los siguientes elementos de otro arreglo en java?

Tags: java, array, java-8, java-ee

En java, tengo definido un primer arreglo de caracteres de maximo 4 elementos, y un segundo arreglo tambien de caracteres que es llenado por entrada del usuario de maximo 4 elementos.

Quiero comparar el primer elemento(indice[0]) del primer arreglo con cada uno de los elementos del otro arreglo, y asi sucesivamente con cada elemento del primer arreglo(que sea comparado con cada uno de los elementos del otro arreglo)

Se que no puedo usar el operador == ya que compara referencias, y es lo mismo que el metodo equals()

El ejercicio dicta que solo puedo usar bucles o la clase Arrays y su metodo equals(), he intentado de varias maneras aplicando logica pero ya lo deje hasta aca, no se me da, alguna ayuda?

nota: ambos arreglos son de tipo char

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_INTENTOS; i++) {
            System.out.print("Código " + i + " de 10>> ");
            letrasEntrada = entrada.nextLine();

            if (i == MAX_INTENTOS) {
                perdiste = true;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < LARGO_CODIGO; j++) {
                letrasAdivinador[j] = letrasEntrada.charAt(j);
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < letrasPensador.length; x++) {
                Arrays.equals();


//                if (letrasAdivinador[x] == letrasPensador[x]) {
//                    b += 2;
//                } else {
//                    if (x + 1 < letrasPensador.length && letrasAdivinador[x] == letrasPensador[x + 1]) {
//                        b += 1;
//                    }
//                    if (x + 2 < letrasPensador.length && letrasAdivinador[x] == letrasPensador[x + 2]) {
//                        b += 1;
//                    }
//                    if (x + 3 < letrasPensador.length && letrasAdivinador[x] == letrasPensador[x + 3]) {
//                        b += 1;
//                    }
//                }
            }
```

Comment: `==` no es lo mismo que `equals`. El primero solo compara las referencias. El otro verifica si son equivalentes. Carga el código que intentaste para que la pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario

Comment: Hola Ricardo, faltaría que nos digas que debe hacer tu método cuando encuentra coincidencias.

Comment: De hallar coincidencias, debo aumentar una variable por cada coincidencia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo al título de la pregunta, aunque está claro que tu ejercicio necesita ir más allá.

```
char letrasEntrada[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
char letrasAdivinador[] = { 'c', 'j', 'a', 'm' };

void verificarCoincidencias( char a[], char b[] ) {      
   for( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {         
      for( int ii = 0; ii < b.length; ii++ ) {
         if( a[ i ] == b[ ii ] ) {
            System.out.println( "coincidencia de " + a[ i ]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

La ejecución de este método nos imprime:

```
coincidencia de a  
coincidencia de c
```

Dado el cambio que ocasiona la re-formulación de la pregunta, el siguiente comentario, queda fuera de lugar, pero dado que el tema se toca en los comentarios, me parece correcto dejarlo.

Nota: desaconsejo absolutamente comparar cadenas con **==**, pero es bueno saber, que si las mismas fueron creadas con literales, es perfectamente válido (alarma de contradicción!!!).

Ejemplo válido:
String a = "casa";
String b = "casa";
boolean c = a == b;

Ejemplo no válido:
String a = new String( "casa" );
String b = "casa";
boolean c = a == b;

Ejemplo no válido:
String a = objetoX.getText();
String b = "casa";
boolean c = a == b;

Esto se debe a que a fin de optimizar recursos, cuando se crea una cadena con literal, java verifica si hay otra cadena igual y de haberla, apunta la nueva al mismo lugar de memoría.
Porqué entonces lo desaconsejo?... porque somos animales de costumbres, y tarde o temprano vamos a equivocarnos intentando comparar de esa forma.

Comment: olvidé mencionar que los arreglos son de tipo char, me tira el siguiente error

Cannot resolve method 'equals(char)'
No candidates found for method call letrasPensador[x].equals(letrasAdivinador[z]).

```for (int x = 0; x < letrasPensador.length; x++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < letrasAdivinador.length; z++) {
                    if (letrasPensador[x].equals(letrasAdivinador[z])) {
                        System.out.println( "coincidencia de " + letrasPensador[ i ]);
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: @RicardoAguilar, editté mi respuesta, los **char** se comparan con "**==**".

Comment: Fijate que en la linea que imprime, pusiste **letrasPensador[ i ]** y debes poner **letrasPensador[ x ]**

Comment: muchas gracias, solucionó mi problema, también tomé nota de la lección sobre comparar arreglos.